# Selecting an indented, non-child with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Suppose I have some code like this:

```
<ul id="thing_list">
        <li><div class="thing"><span>Thing 1</span></div></li>
            <div class="properties">
                <ol class="settings">
                    <li><span>Setting 1</span></li>
                        <div class="setting_explain">
                            <p class="explanation"><span>Explanation 1</span></p>
                        </div>
                    <li><span>Setting 2</span></li>
                        <div class="setting_explain">
                            <p class="explanation"><span>Explanation 2</span></p>
                        </div>
```

Suppose I want to make a piece of jQuery that detects when I click on a list element inside the ol.settings element, and then toggles only the p.explanation directly underneath it:

```
$('ol.settings li').click(function(e) {
    ???
  });
```

What goes in place of the question marks? The general version of this question is: How do I select a non-child indented element immediately below a clicked-on element?

My best try was:

```
$('ol.settings li').click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().child().find('p.explanation').eq(0).toggle();
  });
```

This obviously doesn't work, because it will always only toggle the first p.explanation in the list, rather than the first one directly underneath the list element itself.

Comment: Your html is malformed. This could be causing your selectors to not work even if you have the right jquery code. The browser decides how it will handle malformed html and so your parent/child relationships may look different when they are rendered compared to your source code.

`<li><div class="thing"><span>Thing 1</span></div></li>` after this line you start a div which is invalid. I would start with fixing your html then try again on your jquery selector.

Comment: I understand that the way I'm writing this is not textbook, but it's unreadable to me the other way, particularly when the strings inside the elements get large, and there are several per page per div. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you selecting the parent?

```
$('ol.settings li').click(function(e) {
  $(this).children('.explanation').toggle();
});
```

Comment: I tried that, and it doesn't seem to work. The .explanation isn't a child of the li element, since the li closes off on the same line it starts.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I misread your code.
Try this: 
`$(this).next().children('.explanation').toggle();`

Comment: That appears to work. So, indented lines are siblings to things above them if they aren't children?

Comment: @JohnnyApple indentation doesn't matter for HTML (unless you're using a preprocessor). In jQuery `next()` simply looks for the next element. the children looks for `.explanation` within that next element

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('ol.settings li').click(function(e) {
    $(this).siblings('.setting_explain').find('p.explanation').toggle();
  });
```

Comment: This will consider that the setting_explain is on same level as li.

Comment: This does not work, because I don't think 'setting_explain' is a sibling to our li. It's indented. I tried it, and it toggles the first p.explanation in the list no matter what list element you click on.

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid HTML markup, the `div.setting_explain` should come under `li`. Please check the following code snippets.

```js
$('ol.settings li').click(function(e) {
  $(this).find('p.explanation').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="thing_list">
  <li>
    <div class="thing"><span>Thing 1</span></div>
    <div class="properties">
      <ol class="settings">
        <li><span>Setting 1</span>
          <div class="setting_explain">
            <p class="explanation"><span>Explanation</span></p>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li><span>Setting 2</span>
        <div class="setting_explain">
            <p class="explanation"><span>Explanation</span></p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why should that div go inside li? The sub-paragraph should be considered part of the original line?

Comment: `div` cannot be the direct child for `ol`. `li`s alone will be its direct children. Just think the sibling of  `li` will be `li` only not `div`.

Comment: Interesting. The way I have it written does exactly what I want it to, but I will certainly look into restructuring it. Thank you for your suggestions!